# Split LineString into several LineStrings if distance to next Point is > than a given threshold

Tags: python, geometry, distance, points, shapely

I have a shapely Point list:

```
0     POINT (527644.217 5340266.216)
11    POINT (527644.921 5340266.268)
22    POINT (527645.889 5340266.246)
34    POINT (527646.423 5340266.200)
45    POINT (527646.979 5340266.127)
...
```

and created a LineString.

[image: Too long distance examples shown with arrow]

*The arrow in the picture shows the example of a too long distance between two Points.*

I tried to go through a loop and create a new LineString **if the distance to the next point is too long.**
But it does not do the right thing.

```
liness=list()
start=0

for i in range(0,len(gdf.geometry)-1):

  dist=gdf.geometry.iloc[i].distance(gdf.geometry.iloc[i+1])

  if dist > line_tresh:
   
   #List of Points which are too far away
   points_too_far_away.append(LineString([gdf.geometry.iloc[i],gdf.geometry.iloc[i+1]]))
   
   #list of new separated LineStrings 
   liness.append(LineString(gdf.geometry[start:i-1].tolist()))
   

   start=i
```

Is there any better way to get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `apply` method with `shapely`'s `distance` function. Here's an example:

```py
# Setting up example 
import pandas as pd
import shapely

# This function merges points into a LineString when the 
# distance between consecutive points is smaller than the
# dist_threshold variable.
def trip_maker(input_df, geometry_column, dist_threshold):
    
    input_df_columns = input_df.columns[:]
    new_geometry_column = geometry_column + "_"
    df[new_geometry_column] = df[geometry_column].shift(-1)
    
    def my_dist(in_row):
        return in_row[geometry_column].distance(in_row[new_geometry_column])
    
    df['seq_dist'] = df.loc[:df.shape[0]-2].apply(my_dist, axis=1)
    
    df['break'] = (df['seq_dist'] > dist_threshold).shift(1)
    df.loc[0,'break'] = True
    
    df['Trip_ID'] = df['break'].astype(int).cumsum()
    
    def my_line_maker(in_grp):
        if len(in_grp) == 1:
            return list(in_grp)[0]
        else:
            return shapely.geometry.LineString(list(in_grp))
    
    trip_df = df.groupby(['Trip_ID']).agg({geometry_column:my_line_maker}).reset_index()
    
    input_df = input_df.drop([this_col for this_col in input_df.columns if this_col not in input_df_columns])
    
    return trip_df

# Testing the function
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':range(9),
                   'wkt':['POINT (0 0)',
                          'POINT (0 3)',
                          'POINT (0 4)',
                          'POINT (0 5)',
                          'POINT (0 7)',
                          'POINT (0 10)',
                          'POINT (0 11)',
                          'POINT (0 12)',
                          'POINT (0 15)']})

df['geom'] = df['wkt'].apply(shapely.wkt.loads)

trip_df = trip_maker(df, 'geom', 2)
```

In this example, the new `trip_df` `DataFrame` will contain the merged LineStrings.